# File synchronization solution for controlling type of sync for subfolders and devices?

Tags: file-synchronization

I have an app (Obsidian) that having this data structure:

```
Main Data/
├─ App Data/
│  ├─ Plugin Data/
│  │  ├─ Files.json
│  ├─ Files.json
├─ Files.md
```

I want to share the data to various people (or devices). Depending on their [expertise level](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Five-levels-of-expertise_fig2_283960065) of the app, I want to have different types of sync to their devices:

| Level | Files in `Main Data` | Files in `App Data` | Files in `Plugin Data` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Novice/First setup | 1-way | Download once, then ignored | 1-way |
| Advanced beginner | 2-way | Ignored | 1-way |
| Competent | 2-way | Ignored | Ignored |

Can you suggest me some solutions for this? Here are what I have tried and their limitation:

- Google Drive: lack of ignore feature
- [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/): the management of devices and subfolders are too complicated when the network grows
- Git: too advanced for non-technical users

The Wikipedia page [Comparison of version-control software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version-control_software) lists a great deal of software to try, but the criteria I need is not there.

I need it to have renames/moves and conflict detection. Other non-required options:

- Free
- Multi-platform: Windows, Mac, Android, iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to make a custom [installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_(computer_programs)#Installer) and use git under the hood to clone the repo. The app will have an auto-pull feature, and if the user needs to push data upstream, they will need to be educated or tutored about git.

My next question: [Simple installer-maker for minimal and graphical setup](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/84708/6389)