# Simple installer-maker for minimal and graphical setup

Tags: graphic-design, installer

I want to make an installer that basically:

- Silently install other programs
- Run a shell script
- Clone a git repo

<sub>It's a way to solve [File synchronization solution for controlling type of sync for subfolders and devices?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/84233/6389)</sub>

I'd like it to have a creative way to impress users, maybe a slide of images during installation. Inno Setup doesn't seem to be able to do so. Users only need to click one time to choose the location. I have looked at [List of installation software - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) but not sure what to choose. The priorities are:

- Be able to create a creative graphical interface
- Low price

It will be on Windows.

I'm also looking for such installer templates for ideas. For example, this is the skin of [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I decided to write a small Winform C# application for this. I was advised to stay away from Python (for its terribleness at GUI) and Node.js Electron (for its terribleness at memory: a simple `hello world` app requires you to run a whole instance of Chrominum). However, since the app is small and simple, I guess those weaknesses are not significant.